# WOOCOMMERCE Single Product Layout Customisation

Tags: css, wordpress, layout, woocommerce

I've been a grateful recipient of the advice being offered to others posting questions on Stackoverflow for a few months now.  I thought I'd come out the shadows and see if anyone is kind enough to help me with a specific problem I haven't been able to find the answer too on here or other sources about woocommerce.

I'm doing a home project for my brother in law whilst travelling to work on the train, but I'm struggling to get the WOOCOMMERCE product page within my site to look how I'd like it to look.

I'm trying to get the product summary information stretching across the screen to appear  above the product images with everything centered on the page.
So far I have used remove/add actions in the functions.php file to filter/order items to basically how I'd like them displayed. 
As a result in full screen mode it still looks the same, with images to the left of the summary info, but however in a narrower screen mode the summary info is above the images.  Any idea what that is all about?

You can see what I mean on my test domain > http://cowbay.co.uk/?product=el-fregadero

If I can achieve this, I'd then also like to remove the featured image and just have large thumbnails which can then bring up the lightbox when clicked.

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following in your CSS

```
.woocommerce #content div.product div.summary, 
.woocommerce div.product div.summary, 
.woocommerce-page #content div.product div.summary, 
.woocommerce-page div.product div.summary{
    /* float: right; */
     width: 100%
}

.woocommerce #content div.product div.images, 
.woocommerce div.product div.images, 
.woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images, 
.woocommerce-page div.product div.images{
    margin: auto;
    /*float:left;*/
    /*width: 48%; */  <-- you can change it to 80% if you wish
}
```

Comment: Wonderful - thank you
It worked a treat, but I don't understand however how floating the summary right and floating the images left has managed to arrange them correctly?  Obviously I'm not great with CSS.

Comment: We are actually removing the floating property for both items.  Floating the items (divs) aligns them to right or left (i.e. left/right aligned) and the width (at a %) forces them not to be wider than certain size which creates the two-column layout.  By removing the floating property and not limiting the width, we are forcing them to be the default width (100%) and, hence, be shown on top of each other.

Comment: On second reading I get it now.
Does this give me problems for trying to center the whole product display or should I still be able to do this?  Do you have any suggestions (pushing my luck - I know :))

Comment: centering the product display is accomplished by using `margin: auto;` (it centers it on the parent `div`)

Comment: I think I finally got it, although not with the way above.  Thank you for your help.
I'm now struggling with something else, but that is a separate question.